# avoiding negative values in C++

Tags: c++, math

I have the following function, and I tried to avoid negative values by including the if statement, but it didn't help. 
...suggestions on how I might fix this...

```
double G(double S, double X, double r, double div, double k, double T)
{
  double g=0;
  g=Phi(d1(S,X,r,div,k,T))/(exp(-div*T)*S*k*sqrt(T));
 if((isnan)(g) || (isinf)(g) || (g<0)) g=0;
  return g;
}
```

Comment: What are you saying?  The function G still returns negative values in some situations?

Comment: yes indeed, it is returning values like 2.17691e-06 in scenarios where it should be returning 0

Comment: 2.17691e-06 is not a negative number.  It is the same as 0.00000217691

Comment: @itcplpl: That value isn't negative. Understand that floating points are "lossy": they only use a finite amount of memory, so the answer won't be exact. That `2.176891e-06` is really close to 0, and your program should probably consider it "essentially zero".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the syntax is a little bit off. Try this:

```
double G(double S, double X, double r, double div, double k, double T)
{
  double g=0;
  g=Phi(d1(S,X,r,div,k,T))/(exp(-div*T)*S*k*sqrt(T));
  if(isnan(g) || isinf(g) || (g<0)) g=0;
  return g;
}
```

Comment: changed it, but I still get the same negative values.

Comment: Can you please post some sample input and output?

Answer (score 2):

The value you are getting is not negative. 
2.17691e-06 is the exponential representation for 2.17691 x 1/1000000 = 0.00000217691.
Have a look at [exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Negative_integer_exponents).

if you don't want to show the exponentiation sign, consider setting the precision of the digit before showing/using g.
One of the ways to set precision is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the value of a non-double type variable while calling this function? 
Are you getting any warnings? That should give you a clue.